# How to Implement Real Time Notifications in Magento

Tags: magento2

I don't know is it possible or not.

Would like to display real-time notifications to the Customer Profile.

I've custom functionality in the M2 store where user can like products so if he likes certain products then the seller of that product receive this notification.

**You can keep FB in Mind.**

How to achieve this? any guide OR Any references?